# How to control VMWare's virtual machines' audio in c#?

Tags: c#, vmware-workstation

When I used "vmrun list" to get the running virtual machines in vmware workstation, I got the path

```
Total running VMs: 2
Absolute-path-to-virtual-machine1.vmx
Absolute-path-to-virtual-machine2.vmx
```

When I Check my application's volume settings, I saw two "VMware Workstation VMX" settings and "vmware-vmx.exe" process as images
[Volume Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5t96.png)
[Task Manager Processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQdKi.png)

I want to control these vm's volume using c# and AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio in my host, but I cannot get the process id of each virtual machine by "vmrun list" command, so I cannot get the correct IAudioSession object in c# to control them

Comment: You can't control the volume in the guest system from the host.  You can do it INSIDE the VM, but not from outside.  Of course you can't get an IAudioSession, since the VM might not even be running Windows.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm pretty sure that those are on the host, in the image there are two sliders, one for each VM. That's also alluded to in the question.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried to control the volume of two "vmware-vmx.exe" processes in the host(NOT volume inside guest system), but I am not sure which is machine1, which is machine2

Comment: It has been suggested that you use `vmware-cmd /path/to/xxx.vmx getpid`.

Comment: I got vmware-cmd not a command ,exe or batch error